# custom xml in spring

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to introduce custom syntax in spring xml, and my first look was: "http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/extensible-xml.html".

I don't really like the fact that it seems to require DOM parsing, and it doesn't appear to support child elements very well. For example I want to do things like:

```
<a:tag1 id="mybean"><a:tag2><a:tag3 /><a:tag3 /></a:tag2><a:tag1>
```

and have spring convert that to something along the lines of:

```
<bean id="myclass" class="....tag1">
<property name="tag2">
    <bean class="....tag2">
        <util:list>
            <bean class="....tag3" />
            <bean class="....tag3" />
        </util:list>
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

I was about to completely give up on this idea when I ran across apache xbean project:
[xbean](http://geronimo.apache.org/xbean/). Which looks like exactly what I want.

So my questions are:
1) philisophical whining: why doesn't spring support something like this out of the box? It seems like it's clearly a better solution, and usually spring is ahead of the curve rather than behind it.

2) Is there a way to use JAXB annotations with the xbean ant plugin rather than re-annotating my beans with all the xbean annotations?!

3) is the xbean ant plugin still actively being maintained? The documentation claims it's using something called annogen, and the documentation link on the xbean site for that is broken: [annogen](http://annogen.codehaus.org/javadocs/annogen/overview-summary.html#overview_description).

4) is this the right solution for what I want to do, or are there other viable alternatives based on what I want to accomplish?

Comment: A more basic question: Why do you want to introduce your own XML schema? It's quite a lot of extra work.

Comment: Well, it started like this: I wrote an XML schema using JAXB and some annotations and it was quite easy, and expresses the concept (much) more succinctly than spring's relatively verbose xml. The suggestion by others was it would be more intuitive to use my library if the XML could be expressed directly in a spring configuration file, since what I"m actually doing it bean creation. Finally, if my own schema within spring turns out to be a lot of extra work, I don't think it's worth it. I was hoping for something JAXB-like, where you get it almost for free.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [Java-based Spring configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) instead of XML, if things are getting too complicated for Spring's XML syntax.

Comment: That's spring 3 right...? I'm stuck at spring 2.5 at the moment (the rest of the org is on 2.5 and I'm just writing a library). Are those features available in 2.5 via some kind of add-on or something?